# How to access treeRoot field [protected] of hoeffding tree in moa classifier from clojure

Tags: clojure

I am using moa classifier for generating hoeffding tree which gives me a string of its description using getModelDescription,I want to parse the tree by obtaining root and getting child and so on.For getting root I tried using `(.treeRoot moa-classifier)` where treeRoot is the protected field of hoeffding tree and moa-classifier is the tree obtained,but I am getting the following error "No matching field found: treeRoot for class moa.classifiers.trees.HoeffdingTree"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested the technique I am about to describe with the particular class and field you mention, but I have used it with several Java classes that have private fields.

The Java method setAccessible and the Java reflection API can be used to make some fields accessible, where by default they are not: https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector/blob/2ce54cc888cd2a5e58f5f54ae1eae1d5276e966d/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/rrb_vector/debug_platform_dependent.clj#L16-L21

Then you can use the method "get" on the Field object and an instance of the class: https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector/blob/2ce54cc888cd2a5e58f5f54ae1eae1d5276e966d/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/rrb_vector/debug_platform_dependent.clj#L113

Comment: Thanks for your help.How can we make protected methods accessible ?

Comment: Have you tried the technique described there?  I have not, but give it a shot and report back what you find.

Comment: Yes,I got the idea from your answers and used it as ```  f(.getDeclaredField HoeffdingTree "treeRoot")
(.setAccessible f true)
st1 (.get f moa-classifier) and got the output